# How to find unique records from a very big file in java using a scalable solution?

Tags: java, file, collections, duplicates, scalability

I have a file(lets say csv file for our convenience) that can contain as many as multi million records. The file might contain multiple duplicates. Lets say I want to find the unique records but based on only certain columns(Lets say they are the primary columns). Lets say we have a file as:

[image: File ScreenShot]
In this file the first 2 records are not exactly same. But if I consider column1 to be primary then the first 2 records are duplicates for me(as they have same value in column1) and I want only 1 of them in my final result.

In my current approach I am using a Map where the key value is my primary column data and the corresponding mapped value is the entire record.
This way I iterate over all the records and for each record I push its primary column data as key value and the entire record as mapped value respectively. This way whenever a duplicate primary column is encountered during the iterations, it just replaces the record present with the same primary key data(as Map does not allow duplicates).

While this method works fine but I cant scale it to bigger files where it can potentially run out of heap space. Also the time complexity is not good either. Can anyone suggest a better method ?

Comment: Use the right tool for the job - SQL, Hadoop etc...

Comment: Those data is not stored in in any DB and is available only as a raw file so SQL is not a option.

Comment: Still, SQLite for example, is a file, but it will enable you to run queries on it, and does nit require *any* installation

Comment: Sorry didn't get you...as far as my understanding goes SQLite is relational database and I used it while programming android stuff...but how do I use SQLite here?

Comment: You can use sqlite in android. Basically it's a file, so nothing special for you to do. I can write a full answer on how to do it if you want..

Comment: It would be really helpful if you wrote a full answer @ronhash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is off-heap data structures. Try Hazelcast or Redis. Otherwise, if you cannot use anything else, you can vastly decrease your memory requirement, if you store only the line number for the unique records, and you write your output in a second go. You can also increase heap-size, even over your physical memory, but swapping can kill performance. If that is still not enough, you need to write your own off-heap code. You can allocate memory with ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() and write the data there, and use the map to store the offset to your data.